# How to reset error when using Redux actions REQUEST, SUCCESS, FAILURE in Async situation

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am working on some Async actions using Redux. On the Redux GitHub documentations, one of the way they suggest is to define the following three actions.

```
{ type: 'FETCH_POSTS_REQUEST' }
{ type: 'FETCH_POSTS_FAILURE', error: 'Oops' }
{ type: 'FETCH_POSTS_SUCCESS', response: { ... } }
```

Reference: https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.md

In my project, after an error is received, I will display a message for a few second, then disappear by resetting error to null. The problem I found on the above approach is they are using verbs like SUCCESS and FAILURE, which will make it weird if I use

```
{ type: 'FETCH_POSTS_FAILURE', error: '' }
```

to reset the error because the naming suggest it should dispatch an error. Another way is I define another action

```
{ type: 'FETCH_POSTS_ERROR_RESET' }
```

But using this I will have to introduce 2 actions like

```
{ type: 'FETCH_POST_DATA_EMPTY' }
{ type: 'FETCH_POST_ERROR_RESET' }
```

Is there any other better way to handle this? Is there any philosophy behind in using verbs like SUCCESS and FAILURE instead of FETCH_POST_SET_DATA or FETCH_POST_SET_ERROR?